# Is function continuous if preimage of every open interval is open?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We define $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every open **interval** $(a,b)$ its preimage $f^{-1}\left((a,b)\right)$ is open.

Does it imply that f is continuous?

I know the opposite is not true (e.g for $f(x) = x^{2}$ we have $f^{-1}\left((1,4\right)) = (-2, -1) \cup (1,2) $ which is not an open interval (since any number between -1 and 1 is not there).

It looks like this question has already been answered here  - [Function in which every inverse image of open "interval" is open interval but not continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947411/function-in-which-every-inverse-image-of-open-interval-is-open-interval-but-no) - but unfortunately I am unfamiliar with bases and could not get a good grasp of the answer.

Is there an easy way to prove it without that term?

Comment: This is the relevant comment on that link:

An open set is a union of open intervals, and the inverse image of a union of the union of the inverse images, so... – Cheerful Parsnip Oct 8 '18 at 18:08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Because preimages work nicely with set operations.

If you take any open set $V\subset \mathbb R$, you can write $V=\bigcup_j(a_j,b_j)$ (this is very easy to prove: for every point in $V$ there is an interval that contains the point and is contained in $V$). Thus
$$
f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(\bigcup_j(a_j,b_j))=\bigcup_j f^{-1}((a_j,b_j))
$$
is a union of open sets so open. So $f$ is continuous.